# Identifying the columns having duplicate column value with Different column name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

How to identify the columns in a data frame with same column_value But with different column name , we need to list both the column , here i am able to list only one of them.

```
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
        'name': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'age' : [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
'name_dup': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
'age_dup': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['id', 'name','age','name_dup','age_dup'])
```

[image: Data View]

Like in the image ,one can observe that `name` and `name_dup` have same column values but column names are different With the below Function i am able to get only `name` as an output as shown below where expected is `name_dup`.

```
    def duplicate_columns(frame):
    groups = frame.columns.to_series().groupby(frame.dtypes).groups
    dups = []

    for t, v in groups.items():

        cs = frame[v].columns
        vs = frame[v]
        lcs = len(cs)

        for i in range(lcs):
            iv = vs.iloc[:,i].tolist()
            for j in range(i+1, lcs):
                jv = vs.iloc[:,j].tolist()
                if iv == jv:
                    dups.append(cs[i])
                    break

    return dups 

 duplicate_columns(df)
```

Output of Above Code is Shown Below :

[image: Actual Output]

**Expected List Duplicate columns Output**

`name` and `name_dup` `age` and `age_dup`.

Here further to This keep drop any one of the column and rename the new column from `list_check` if we have a list of column name :

```
list_check  =  ['name','age']
```

**Expected DataFrame**

[image: Expected Output]

**Note** : It is not compulsory that it will always be `colname` will be `colname_dup` it can also be `lname`.

Comment: I don't see `age_dup` column in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean by:

```
s = df.T.duplicated().reset_index()
vals = s.loc[s[0], 'index'].tolist()
colk = df.columns.drop(vals)
print(vals)
print(colk)
print(df.drop(vals, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
['name_dup', 'age_dup']
['id', 'name', 'age']
  id name  age
0  1    A    1
1  2    B    2
2  2    B    2
3  3    C    3
4  3    D    3
```

Comment: Expected vals is ['name','name_dup','age', 'age_dup']

Comment: @NabiShaikh Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Data frame output is perfect , but i also want to know the other column name also because  from this code i am getting to know `name` as duplicate column but if in other column is names as say 'colk' so this would be great info that .some one has named a similar content column value with different column name which is `colk` .

Comment: @NabiShaikh Edited better?

Comment: This is good to understand when when your data set has small no of column , but in case of more then 100 columns , if i want to identify name_dup and name have same column value but the column name is different . in that case it would difficult to understand. By any means can we list column differently , for example name and name_dup have same column value . would be more precise ..

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

output:

```
  id name age
0  1    A   1
1  2    B   2
2  2    B   2
3  3    C   3
4  3    D   3
```

Comment: Yes this is the end result , but the naming should be as per `list_check` we also want a list all columns with the common column value